# How do I add custom environment variables to ABP.IO Angular?

Tags: angular, abp

**ABP Framework version:** v4.3.0

**User Interface** Angular v11.2.11

How do I add custom environment variables to environment.ts?
If I add say `customVar` and try to read it in a component it I get the error `Property 'customVar' does not exist on type 'Environment'`.